# Django thumbnails from S3

Tags: django, image, amazon-s3, django-templates

There many questions regarding this topic, but i didnt find any exact answer to my problem. I am building a django app where users can store photos and they are private. When showing them the thumbnails I am having to show the thumbnails by generating signed url from S3. But it takes quite a long time. I wanted to know is there any better option that I am missing.???

Sorl-Thumbnail also has the same problem. I have looked at it and didn't find any better option.
Is there any other option where the source of the image cant be visible?? That might also work.
Please help me as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you are asking, but sounds like you have some slowness because you are generating thumbnails on the fly. If that's the case, you could improve performance pre-generating the thumbnails-- generate them when you store the image instead of when you request them.

I don't see much room for improvement if you are concerned with the performance of signed requests because your images are private in S3, without changing your application design. In some cases, it's acceptable to use hard-to-guess URLs for private photos. For example, I believe Flickr does that.

Comment: Generating urls while storing the images is not a possibility as S3 creates unique url every time a user request it to be seen. It will only mean the first request is fast and rest other is not. And secondly the url created is only valid for a particular period of time....